# Simulating multiple bootstrap modal popups in javascript in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to use the technique described on GetBootStrap.com, for simulating multiple modal popups, described here:
See “Toggle between modals” here…
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/However,

But since I am doing this from an ASP.NET Core MVC project, I’m loading the popup’s data and showing it via  javascript. The problem is I don’t know how to specify the bootstrap attributes, data-bs-target, data-bs-toggle, and data-bs-dismiss, in javascript.

The link to the modal popup…

```
<a class="details href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
```

HTML for the popup…

```
<div id="modal2" class="modal" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">My Title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
                    data-bs-target="#modal1" 
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Back
                </button>
                <!--This button omitted because it’s handled in script… -->
                <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" 
                    data-bs-target="#modal3" 
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Open 3rd
                </button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script to load data and show the popup…

```
        $("#myGrid .details").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/myController/EditPopup",
                data: { "id": id },
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#juvModal").find(".modal-body").html(response);

                    //data-bs-target/popup/dismiss attributes here???

                    $('#juvModal').modal('show');
                }
                . . .
```

So my question is, How to specify data-bs-target/popup/dismiss attributes in the success function (or elsewhere)?